# Cordova android splashscreen are distorted

Tags: android, ios, cordova, splash-screen

I have a Cordova app with a splashscreen at start. The splashscreen is shown but it's distorted. It seems to don't take the good resolution.

My splash is a Bitmap image, I don't care if its cropped but I don't want it to be distorted.

I have the following structure with splashscreen at differents size according to the [doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens):

```
drawable-xhdpi/
  splash.png   // 960 x 720px
drawable-hdpi/
  splash.png   // 640 x 480px
drawable-mdpi/
  splash.png   // 470 x 320px
drawable-ldpi/
  splash.png   // 426 x 320px
```

Is it a Cordova bug? Did I miss something?

I tested with few devices like Galaxy s3 mini, HTC but I got the samed problem on each device.

It works well in iOs.

I used cordova 3.3 and upgraded it recently to 3.4 but got the problem still persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just changed the sizes to:

```
xlarge (xhdpi): 720 x 1280
large (hdpi): 480 x 800
medium (mdpi): 320 x 480
small (ldpi): 200 x 320
```

And it works perfectly

Answer (score 14):

In my case, adding

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
```

to config.xml solved the distortion problem for me.

Comment: I'm creating an android app using react native and there is no config.xml available, could you suggest how can i add preference?

I have `AndroidManifest.xml` file, can i add the preference over there?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who came across this question and is using *capacitor*:

## Capacitor < 4

There is a similar setting like the one suggested for *Cordova* that can be added to `capacitor.config.json`

```
"SplashScreen": {
    "androidScaleType": "CENTER_CROP"
}
```

There's an open issue on Github with more configuration examples [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-assets/issues/163)

## Capacitor >= 4

Unfortunately, starting from capacitor 4 splash screens are being squashed despite the settings, so the only way to make it work seems to be **9 patch images** (can be managed in Android Studio directly).

Following this [tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-dynamic-universal-splash-screen-for-capacitor-android/) solved the issue for me, and this seems the best way to deal with future capacitor changes.